# Referencing mixed Fortran & C in doxygen

Tags: c, fortran, doxygen

My situation:

*file_api.h*

```
/*!
   \brief blabla
   \params ...description of many parameters..
*/
int api_function(...very long parameter list ...);
```

*file_api.c*

```
int api_function(...very long parameter list ...)
{
   return api_function_(...very long parameter list ...);
}
```

*file_api.f*

```
!> \copydoc ????what to put here???
integer function api_function(...very long parameter list ...)
```

Problem is that `Fortran` and `C` functions have exactly same name, so only way I can reference `C` function is via full function declaration:

```
!> \copydoc api_function(...very long parameter list ...)
```

which exceeds size of Fortran line (132 characters) and makes code a bit ugly to read.

My questions:

1. Is there any possibility to split autolink to more lines? Something like:

   `!> \copydoc api_function(...very long`

   `!!          long parameter list ...)`
2. Is there any way how to use filename+function name in autolink instead of param list? Something like:

   `!> \copydoc file_api.h::api_function()`
3. Set custom link to object and not use autolink? (so I can set that `C` function will have link `api_function__()` instead of `api_function()`)

Comment: Try **!> \copydoc api_function()**

Comment: @cup That is the whole point, this one triggers warning about recursive copy of documentation, because it references itself and not C function

Comment: Do it the other way round: from C reference the fortran function as module::function().  Not sure how you would do it for F77.

Comment: Fortran api_function() is not in the module, because it must be callable from C.

Comment: This is a great question. Pity there isn't an answer to it as I'm trying to solve the question myself. Will update if I find a solution